# bootstrap accordion menu opening and close issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have integrated a bootstrap accordion menu onto my site [Click here](http://portland-design.com/wp/wp-portland/news-blog/)

The issue i am having when one toggle is open the other toggle doesn't close
I am assuming this is a css issue as i can not figure any extra properties i need to apply to my html in order to get this work.

at the moment when the toggle menu is collapsed the css property goes to

```
.collapse .in { display: block }

                    <article class="panel-heading" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#NewsFive" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                    <div class="panel-heading-date">
                        <span>06/10/2016</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-title panel-news">
                            <article>

                            </article>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
                <div id="NewsFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">

                    <div class="video-wrapper">
                                <source src="/assets/videos/the-future-of-retail.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="playpause"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
```

Just wonder if anyone can spot anything that maybe causing this issue

Comment: May I know the exact issue and I have observed accordion are working fine. Do you want toggle option for that? (When click on 1st accordion tab then 2nd accordion tab will close)

Comment: Accordion works fine. The issue i am having when one toggle is open the other toggle doesn't close

Comment: Please check your provided html code because it's having much errors

Comment: The class="in" is controlling if it is opened or closed on element id="NewsFive"

Comment: @Zorken17 the class opens the first accordion menu by default, don't think it has anything to do with that

Comment: try to take the class away and it will close. It is the same for all your tiles

Comment: it doesn't, when that class it taken away the top accordion is closed rather than opened

Comment: What's the reason for the down vote ? This is actually a relevant issue that can help many bootstrap users

Comment: Data-parent has mismatch with id selector. Use **.accordion** instead

Comment: @SanthoshKumar can you right that up in an answer

Comment: Does it worked for you

Comment: nope it doesn't actually. I've just applied it to the url given above doesn't seem to work

Comment: @NewBoy your html structure is wrong. you are add panel-body in panel-heading class so please set it out side the panel-heading  class and check it.

Comment: reply me if it works

Comment: @SanthoshKumar i don't really follow what you mean by it's not the same. The example you've provide looks exactly the same as the structure i have

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurred due to **miss matching of ID's of Tab heading and tab content**.

Please check the accordion carefully as well as the **aria-controls="collapseOne"** and **aria-labelledby="headingOne"** are need to be match.

```css
#accordion .panel-heading { padding: 0;}
#accordion .panel-title > a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    outline: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.panel-group {
    position: relative;
}
.panel-heading-date {
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 18px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.accordio-panel-title {
    margin-left: 120px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.accordio-panel-title .panel-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="main">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">                  
     <div class="panel-heading-date">
      10/13/2016
     </div>
     <div class="accordio-panel-title" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
       <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #1</h4>
     </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                      <li>The titles are block, so you don't have to click the text part to activate it</li>
                      <li>Indicators for expand / collapsing items</li>
                      <li>Removed title links' obnoxious :hover  underlinings, and outlines.</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
     <div class="panel-heading-date">
      10/13/2016
     </div>
     <div class="accordio-panel-title collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group Item #2</h4>
     </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
     <div class="panel-heading-date">
      10/13/2016
     </div>
     <div class="accordio-panel-title collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible G roup Item #3</h4>
     </div>                
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div> 
<div>
```

Comment: I've checked out your solution it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you share your updated demo.We can know that what is going wrong.

Comment: check the link above - http://portland-design.com/wp/wp-portland/news-blog/

Comment: Thank you...I have noticed some issues in your demo. Now I'm fixing those fixes and update you. :)

Comment: Apparently I need to run javascript that closes the other accordions. It looks as if this works by adding the `in` class to show an accordion and removing the `in` class to hide an accordion. If Javascript works, i'll post the answer

Comment: Not need any JS and Bootstrap has default feature for Accordion. Now I'm working on this demo: Just adding your CSS classes: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/q8pX9

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what you have done different in this demo ?